# How do I draw a class which extends from a class in the external package such as abstract class BroadcastReceiver in Class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

May I know the way to represent my class object in UML Class Diagram which extends the class from external package such as abstract class BroadcastReceiver?

For instance I have the following class :-

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{        
    private bool isConnected;

    public MyBroadcastReceiver (Context context)
    {            
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {                                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple Generalization:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer. Just to be sure if it's recommended to include the `BroadcastReceiver's` abstract method `OnReceive` in the classes? or just leave it as blank?

Comment: You can do both, depending on what information you want to give. Overview diagrams often leave out attributes/operations.

Comment: I see, which means it's not necessary to include all attributes/operations I have implemented in my coding into the class diagram, but NECESSARY information only. Is that correct?